# Filter function based on dynamic criteria from another cell

Tags: google-sheets

In google spreadsheet, I try to create a dynamic filter which depends on the content of another cell. Actually I need something like this:

```
if A1 = "1" {
  filter (A70:D73;E70:E73="A")
}
if A1 = "2" {
  filter (A70:D73;F70:F73="B")
}
```

Anyone an Idea how to create such a dynamic filter?

Comment: Somthing like this? `=filter(a70:d73,e70:e73=if(a1=1,"a",if(a1=2,"b",""))`

Comment: almost, but this won't give the result I need. 
when a1=2  it need to use f70:f73 as criteria

Comment: Crap! `=If(a1=1,filter(a70:d73,e70,e73="a"),if(a1=2,a70:a73,f70:f73="b","")`

Comment: Is it correct A70:D73 in the first case? isn't it A70:A73?

Comment: @MauricioMoraes You are right, this isn't correct, i've changed this in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a kinky solution for this.
first I've divided the problem in some smaller portions.

I've created an extra column what I call the 'filter' column. 
Next to this filter column i've matrix with all posible filter options

In this spreadsheet you can see an example of this solution

[Dynamic matrix filter spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10XWD3oSqukFLjUf8LFizbKcdbzyrkAIEpm0Wvq-_558/edit?usp=sharing)

To determ if an item is a part of the matrix I simply use a "Countifs"
So for each row in the matrix:

```
=if($D$1<>"";COUNTIFS(C4:G4;$D$1);"")
```

Field $D$1 is the input for the filter. This is making the filter dymanic, because you put every formula in this field, but in this example the cell is just field in with a text

The filter column (B4:B9) results in a number. And this number is used to make the filter

```
=filter(A4:A9;B4:B9=1)
```

Here is looked up if B4:B9  =1 but you can put a cell for  "1" too, so you get even more flexibility and make the filter dynamic in each way you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=filter(    A70:A73; OR(  AND(A1=1; E70:E73="A") ; AND(A1=2; F70:F73="B")  )    )
```

Obs: I usually "indent" with spaces these big formulas. But in some cases its better to create hidden columns with partial results, so that the formulas don't get too scary.

Obs2: Its also good to lock the columns or rows that you don't want to change, like this:

```
=filter(    $A$70:$A$73; OR(  AND($A$1=1; $E$70:$E$73="A") ; AND($A$1=2; $F$70:$F$73="B")  )    )
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works, however, the formula will be extreme long, since I need about 10 different filters.

Comment: @Richard That's quite what I was saying in the observations: to use columns with partial results. I'm glad it solved your problem.

Comment: BTW I like the use of indent within the formula, never seen that before, but I definitely gonna use that

Answer (score 0):

Another way that may be a bit more "scalable" (but maybe not):

`=FILTER(CHOOSE(A1,A70:D73,A70:A73,...),CHOOSE(A1,E70:E73,F70:F73,...)=CHOOSE(A1,"A","B",...)`